# UIView not erasing itself before redrawing

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I have this in a custom UIView subclass init function:

`self.clearsContextBeforeDrawing=YES`

However, each time I call `setNeedsDisplay`, it draws on top of the prior view's drawing, rather than drawing fresh.

How can I make sure a UIView's drawing context is empty when it draws again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your view is opaque, you must set the `backgroundColor` property of the view to something to make it clear the view properly.

If it's not opaque that should work and ought to clear the view with transparent black.